# No module named (Python)

Tags: python, function, module

I created a file called Despike_Goring_Nikora, with contains two functions:

```
def ExcludeOutlierEllipsoid3D(xi, yi, zi, theta, universalThreshold):
```

and

```
def PhaseSpaceDespike1d(vel):
```

I put this file in Python Scripts folder, and assured to add this one to path.

In another file called ADP_data, which is in a different folder, I'd like to call these functions. So at the beginning I was doing

```
import Despike_Goring_Nikora
```

I also tried

```
from Despike_Goring_Nikora import PhaseSpaceDespike1d
```

But all I receive is

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Despike_Goring_Nikora'
```

Comment: is your file name is Despike_Goring_Nikora or Despike_Goring_Nikora.py?

Comment: it's Despike_Goring_Nikora.py

Comment: This seems the issue of init file. You need to create __init__.py file in your directory.

Comment: what do you mean? just create init.py and place in the directory? but in which one? the same as the script or the same of the function?

Comment: I created this file, but it's not working still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a particular directory to be considered as a module in python you need to create a `__init__.py` file inside it.

Besides you need to ad `.py` to your files:

- `Despike_Goring_Nikora.py`,
- `APP_Data.py`.

Also you're naming your functions/modules in a wrong way. Please try to stick to Python naming convention.

Comment: What's the point of having the folder Python Scripts automatically created in Python if I can't use the scripts inside it?

Comment: Please add `tree .` output to your question.

Comment: \My Documents\PythonScripts\routines\Despike_Goring_Nikora and \\My Documents\Documents\SeagrassData\data\sawhorse\ADP\ADP_data